# Viewing queries history in django

Tags: python, django

I need something to view the queries happened ( creating or updating or deleting ) in DB tables in Django, I want it to be able to be used by the user, not at the admin panel

Comment: If you want suggestions for django third party packages, this is not the right place to ask. Library recommendation questions are off-topic for stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a model history (sometimes also called "audit trail").
In [this link](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/model-audit/) there is a comparisson of different packages that can be used for audit/history of models.

As I already pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50029836/9225671),
I use [django-simple-history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which comes with a nice integration to view the list of changes of every model instance in the admin.

For my use case at least, django-simple-history provided me with what I needed, and so far I did not face any issues with it, even though this package does **NOT** track history of `ManyToManyField` (for that see related questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312334/how-can-i-store-history-of-manytomanyfield-using-django-simple-history) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209655/history-of-a-manytomanyfield-in-django-simple-history) or the [Github issue](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history/issues/16)).

---

Now, if you want the end user to be able to see the history (but not through the admin panel), then you would need to add a few pages for that.

For example, you could add a list view for each model using djangos generic [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview).